# Pinging server in Bash script,

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

can anyone help me figure out whats wrong in this script ?
im a begineer

```
echo "whats the server address ?"
read server
ping -c 4 $server > /dev/null
result=$?
if [ $result = 0 ]
echo " ping succ"
else echo "ping unsuccessful"                                                                                                                                                fi
```

Comment: How is it not working for you? We can't address your problem if you don't tell us what error or problem you have. But for starters the `if` syntax is wrong. Search "bash if else".

Comment: https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Please describe what is the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your if syntax is wrong. It should be as follows. Notice the `then` and the closing `fi`

```
if ...; then
    #code
else
    #code
fi
```

You can shorten your code by doing the pinging inside `if`

```
if ping -c 4 $server > /dev/null; then 
    echo "ping succ"
else
    echo "ping unsuccessful"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed to close the if condition

```
echo "whats the server address ?"
read server
ping -c 4 $server > /dev/null
result=$?
if [ $result = 0 ]
echo "ping successful"
else 
echo "ping unsuccessful"
fi
```